# $G \subset e^{\frac{2kπ} {n} i}, k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Show that $G$ is a group under multiplication

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers, solution-verification

Let $G$ be the subset of complex numbers of the form $e^{\frac{2k\pi} {n} i}, n,k \in \mathbb{Z+}$. Show that $G$ is a group under multiplication. How many elements does $G$ have?

Associativity under multiplication is there in complex domain.

Identity is when $e^{\frac{2k\pi} {n} i} =1=e^{(2\pi).i}\implies k/n=1 \implies k = n.$

Or, for angle of $0°$.

Inverse for given value of $k$ is given by suitable value of $k$ that achieves the same effect as $-k$. Say, if $\frac{2\pi k}{n} = 30°$ leading to $e^{i \pi/6}= cos(\pi/6)+i.sin(\pi/6)= \frac{\sqrt{3}}2+i.\frac 12$. Then, inverse is obtained by any value ($x+iy$) s.t. $(\frac{\sqrt{3}}2+i.\frac 12)(x+iy)= 1$.

For $k=1, e^{\frac{2\pi} {n} i}$, and for higher integer values of $k$, multiple of the same. But, it is the value of $n$ that matters.
So, infinitely many values are possible.

Confused if analyzed correctly.

*Title has no mention of domain of $n$, and domain of $k$ is $\mathbb{Z}$, as question was. Modified to restrict $k$ to be non-zero positive value, as anyway $e^{0i}=e^{2\pi i}$. Also, made $n$ a non zero integer as none was specified. But, the real issue lies with what set of values $\frac k n$ can take. Ideally, both $k,n$ can be integers, with $n$ being non-zero. But, sign change is not significant as same values of expression can be attained by positive values of $k,n$ too.*

Comment: Important distinction here: do we have $G = \{e^{\frac{k}{n} \cdot 2\pi i} : k, n \in \mathbb Z^+\},$ or $G_n = \{e^{\frac{k}{n} \cdot 2\pi i} : k \in \mathbb Z^+\}$? I would suspect the second one.

Comment: @StephenDonovan please see the edit at the end. The question doesn't have $G_n$. Also, it is exercise from Group theory notes, by Kreher; of exercise 1.1.1 Q.2. It is an evolving set of notes, with more material added in a few years.

Comment: @StephenDonovan kindly tell what difference it would have entailed if it was $G_n$ instead. Am not clear, if then $\mathbb{Z+}$ domain is implied implicitly?

Comment: The difference is that for any fixed $n,$ the group $G_n$ will have finitely many elements, as opposed to the overall group $G$ which is infinite. (Also, something I just noticed: you can't use $-k$ for your inverse because you've defined that the elements of $G$ must have positive $k.$ There is an equivalent which will work though.)

Comment: G contains nth roots of unity for n=1,2,3,…. G is a Group which is countable. G has closure property. It is indeed a Group.

Comment: @StephenDonovan edited the post. Kindly vet the edit on the inverse part.

Comment: The inverse part still needs work: currently you're using the existence of the multiplicative inverse in the complex numbers to justify that one must exist in $G$ but for that to work you need to know that the inverse in $\mathbb C$ is in $G.$ That said you're on the right track about a member of $G$ which "achieves the same effect as" $-k$: can you find one?

Comment: @StephenDonovan In fact, it is multiplication , so confused if had not restricted $k$ to positive integer values, then  $e^{k.\theta. i}. e^{-k.\theta.i} $ would have served the purpose even!

Continuing with my imposed restriction on $k$, and what is stated in post:

 $(√3/2+i.1/2)(x+iy)=1 ,$
$√3/2.x + i.√3/2.y+ i.x/2 - y/2= 1,$

Real part : $√3/2.x -y/2= 1$
Imaginary part : $√3/2.y = -x/2 => √3.y = -x => y = -x/(√3)$

Substitute back value of y in real part:

$√3/2.x -i .x.2 +i.x.2 +\frac{1}{√3.2}
= 1 ,$
=> $x= \frac{√3.2- 1}{3},$
=> $y= -\frac{√3.2- 1}{√3}$

Comment: Well yes, but you would then need to represent that value in $G,$ and you would also need to show that that process is replicable for all possible $k$ and $n.$

Comment: @StephenDonovan how to show the latter part? Second, if had not restricted $k\in\mathbb{Z+}$, then would have by earlier statement chosen $-k$ to get: $e^{i.\theta}.e^{-i.\theta}= (cos(\theta)+i.sin(\theta))(cos(\theta)-i.sin(\theta))= (cos^2(\theta)+sin^2(\theta))= 1$

Comment: The fact that the latter part of my comment would be difficult (or at least tedious) is why I don't recommend this line of reasoning. Basically, instead of trying to find an inverse and then show it's in $G,$ I would try to construct an element of $G$ which is an inverse. (try to use the cyclical nature of the roots of unity)

Comment: @StephenDonovan request an answer or reference to something similar in a text or post here. Can understand cyclical nature of roots of unity, but still stuck with your approach. Answer would be best. Confused if this answer is your approach, seems not - as resembles my approach. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2685081/424260. Or might be need add to it the fact that roots can always be found, as to match your approach.

Comment: @StephenDonovan request answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find an inverse in $G$ for an element $e^{\frac{k}{n} \cdot 2\pi i},$ first we can note that for all integers $a, e^{a \cdot 2\pi i} = 1,$ so we can aim to add to any integer rather than having to add to get back to $0.$

So, let's consider $k' = \lceil \frac{k}{n} \rceil n - k.$ By definition, $\lceil \frac{k}{n} \rceil \geq \frac{k}{n},$ so $\lceil \frac{k}{n} \rceil \cdot n - k \geq 0$ and $k'$ is a positive integer, so $e^{\frac{k'}{n} \cdot 2\pi i} \in G.$ Now notice:

$$\left(e^{\frac{k}{n} \cdot 2\pi i}\right)\left(e^{\frac{k'}{n} \cdot 2\pi i}\right) = e^{\frac{k + k'}{n} \cdot 2\pi i} = e^{\lceil \frac{k}{n} \rceil \cdot 2\pi i} = 1$$

so we have our inverse.

---

My intuition for this comes from the homomorphism from the group of integers mod $n$ under addition to our group $G$ in the "fixed-n" case:

$$f(k) = e^{\frac{k}{n} \cdot 2\pi i} \\ f(k_1 + k_2) = e^{\frac{k_1 + k_2}{n} \cdot 2\pi i} = \left(e^{\frac{k_1}{n} \cdot 2\pi i}\right)\left(e^{\frac{k_2}{n} \cdot 2\pi i}\right) = f(k_1)\cdot f(k_2)$$

Homomorphisms send inverses to inverses, so an additive inverse in the integers mod $n$ would relate to a multiplicative inverse in $G.$ All that remained was to find one which was guaranteed to be positive.